# Python argument unpacking

Tags: python

Sometimes, some functions exchange some really ad-hoc tuples of data.

```
>>> def foo():
...    return (1,2,4)
...
>>> def f(a, b, v):
...    x, y, z = v
...    # ...
...    # suppose there are 2-4 lines of some trivial code
...    # ...
...    print a, b, '(', x, y, z, ')'
...
>>> f(1, 2, foo())
1 2 ( 1 2 4 )
```

The use-case here is that it's really ad-hoc bunch of data, so we don't want to introduce a new class. (We also assume that the tuple itself is just a bunch of data, so that accessing the tuple's elements by index, like `print a, b, '(', v[0], v[1], v[2], ')'` would be really confusing to the reader.)

So, anyway. We decided to pass tuples around, and we want to unpack (deconstruct) them. What's cool, is that you can unpack an argument-tuple right in the function's argument list, so `f` can be simplified just a bit:

```
>>> def f(a, b, (x,y,z)):
...    # ...
...    # the same implementation
...    # ...
...    print a, b, '(', x, y, z, ')'
```

It makes it a bit cleaner to the reader. It's just one line of code, but it's also completely unnecessary code, and it also make the function's signature look cleaner.

Is there are any hidden pitfalls of this technique? 
Is it a generally frowned upon feature (in which case I'm interested in the reason)?

I use python 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If it's "is my program doing something weird and probably not a best practice," the answer looks like a "yes." If it's "is Python doing something weird," then the answer is generally "no, unless it's a Python 2 feature that was removed for Python 3."

Comment: I generally find it turns into an unmaintainable mess in 6 months time when you really can't remember what the tuple element order was. In general when I've done this, I always subsequently regret not making classes ...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, I was asking exactly in the first meaning: "is my program doing something weird and probably not a best practice". What I'm looking for is elaboration on this question. Thank you!

Comment: if you don't mind having two less spaces, you can also write `print a, b, (x, y, z)` in python 2.7

Comment: @Pynchia I would argue these functions are not equivalent: mine prints `1 2 ( 1 2 4 )`, yours `1 2 (1, 2, 4)`, so let's stick to the point! :)

Comment: I would prefer doing `f(1,2,*foo())` and `def f(a,b,x,y,z)` rather than `f(1,2,foo())` and `def f(a, b, (x,y,z))`. It works in python2 and python3 and also keeps your code readable.

Comment: @hgwells f(1,2,*foo()) is also fine, except that now you have to stick to just one tuple, and always put in at the end of the argument list.

Comment: That is correct, it does not allow those other use cases. I believe, in my python3 biased point of view :) , python2/3 compatibility is very important. I would unpack it inside the function or keep it at the end of the args, just for that reason. PS: I would also use future print function for that same reason

Comment: Not all of my projects require python2/3 compatibility, but I strive for readability anyway :) But good to know about the compatibility problem, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python3, the [Tuple Parameter Unpacking feature is removed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/). Per PEP 3113:

> Unfortunately this feature of Python's rich function signature abilities, while handy in some situations, causes more issues than they are worth.

So don't use it; it will make your code Python2-compatible only.
Other reasons to avoid tuple parameter unpacking which are discussed in the PEP include

- Introspection Issues
- No Loss of Abilities If Removed
- Exception To The Rule
- Uninformative Error Messages
- Little Usage

Comment: The code in the OP seems to work in Python 3 (added parentheses around `print` arguments, called with `f(1, 2, (1, 2, 4))`).

Comment: Oh I see, the second snippet, yes. I was focused on the first snippet; my bad.

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you! In the current project I'm not interested in the compatibility, but it's good to know that using it make code less compatible.